# Is an event subscribed to an observable still fired on refresh?

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, refresh

I have an issue which I have been figuring out for a while now.
I have this piece of code:

```
this.service.process(this.Object.id, this.Object.userId,this.pageNr)
.subscribe((data) => {
    this.processed.emit(this.pageNr);
});
```

Now when debugging I see that the process method is called, when I refresh in the middle of the process, I do not see the processed.emit().

So, is it possible that on refresh the process( which is one transaction) goes through, but subscribed "processed" does not happen?

If someone could give a link to more information that would be awesome, or maybe information about how to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to avoid multiple subscription:

```
subscription:Subscription

    ...
    
if(!!this.subscription){
// unsubsribe from old subscription
this.subscription.unsubscribe();

}
this.subscription = this.service.process(this.Object.id, this.Object.userId,this.pageNr)
.subscribe((data) => {
    this.processed.emit(this.pageNr);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but how do I solve the problem. How can I make sure the processed.emit() is executed even when a refresh happens when process is running? Or can I put those 2 in a transaction, is that possible? I am very new to JS.

Comment: multiple subscription will leak your memory...so we will unsubsribe from old one then re subscribe to new one

Comment: useful answer & well reasoning @ZrelliMajdi